# std::lock_guard deadlock in exception handling

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, deadlock

I read in a document that `std::lock_guard` can create an issue in deadlock.  I want to know what is the best practice to handle that situation?

When use `std::lock_guard` in multiple place to handle exception, it will trigger deadlock

Also it will be nice to share more deadlock examples, so I can avoid deadlocks in the future.

My code

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
// // #include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::mutex global_stream_lock;
void worker_thread(std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> iosvc, int i ){
  {
     std::lock_guard   l {global_stream_lock};
     std::cout<<"Thread"<<i<<"started"<<std::endl;
  }
  try{
     std::lock_guard   l {global_stream_lock};
    iosvc->run();
    std::cout<<"Thread "<<i<<"End \n";
  }
  catch(std::exception &ex){
    {
      std::cout << "Message: " << ex.what() << ".\n";
    }
    
  }
}

void throw_an_exception(std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_svc, int counter)
{
  
  {
    std::lock_guard   l {global_stream_lock};
    std::cout << "Throw Exception " << counter << "\n" ;
  }
  
  
  throw(std::runtime_error("The Exception !!!"));
}

int main(void) {
  std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_svc (new boost::asio::io_service);
  std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> worker (new boost::asio::io_service::work(*io_svc));
  std::vector<std::jthread> threads;
  {
    std::lock_guard l {global_stream_lock};
    std::cout << "The program will exit once all work has finished.\n";
  }
  boost::asio::io_service::strand strand(*io_svc);
  //boost::thread_group threads;
  
  for (int i =1; i<=3;++i)
  {
     threads.push_back(std::jthread{&worker_thread, io_svc, i});
  }
 

  // std::chrono::milliseconds sleep_times {1000};
  // std::this_thread::sleep_for(sleep_times);

  io_svc->post(boost::bind(&throw_an_exception, io_svc, 1));
  io_svc->post(boost::bind(&throw_an_exception, io_svc, 2));
  io_svc->post(boost::bind(&throw_an_exception, io_svc, 3));
  io_svc->post(boost::bind(&throw_an_exception, io_svc, 4));
  io_svc->post(boost::bind(&throw_an_exception, io_svc, 5));
  
  

  return 0;

 }
```

Output is

```
The program will exit once all work has finished.
Thread1started
```

I think the deadlock happens because I add std::lock_guard in multiple places

If I remove the lock guard in below code, there will be no deadlock, but just want to know what is the best solution to use `std::lock_guard`?

```
void throw_an_exception(std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_svc, int counter)
{
  
  {
    //commment below will addredd deadlock issue
    //std::lock_guard   l {global_stream_lock};
    std::cout << "Throw Exception " << counter << "\n" ;
  }
  
  
  throw(std::runtime_error("The Exception !!!"));
}
```

Comment: *"It is known that std::lock_guard can have issue in deadlock."* -- This does not uniquely identify your issue. Especially since `std::lock_guard` is not a guard against all deadlocks, just the ones resulting from accidentally failing to unlock a mutex. You should add a more thorough description of your particular case, describing which of the many remaining deadlock scenarios you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

`lock_guard` should only be use for one purpose. Apparently above is a bug

```
try {
  std::lock_guard   l {global_stream_lock};
  iosvc->run();
  std::cout << "Thread "<<i<<"End \n";
} catch(std::exception &ex) {
  {
    std::cout << "Message: " << ex.what() << ".\n";
  }
}
```

Change to:

```
try {
  iosvc->run();
  {
    std::lock_guard l {global_stream_lock};
    std::cout<<"Thread "<<i<<"End \n";
  }
} catch(std::exception &ex) {
  {
    std::lock_guard l {global_stream_lock};
    std::cout << "Message: " << ex.what() << ".\n";
  }
}
```

The variable, **global_stream_lock** from text book, is supposed to be used only for cout.

But it will be appreciated if someone could walk me through it.

How the dead lock is trigger, when I include **iosvc->run();** in the **lock_guard** scope?

Comment: You tried to take the lock you were already holding in the same thread.  That’s deadlock, but isn’t it also obvious?

Comment: it is not that obvious, as another lock happen in  iosvc->run();

Comment: One function locks the mutex then, while holding the lock, calls another function that attempts to lock the mutex. The problem isn't in `lock_guard`; that's just the mechanism that shows the problem. Any other mechanism that locks the mutex would have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `std::mutex global_stream_lock;` change it to `std::recursive_mutex global_stream_lock;`

Comment: While this might prevent a deadlock, wouldn't it also mean that the mutex no longer protects the code it was meant to protect?

Comment: Std:: recursive_ Mutex can also synchronize. Your code is originally locked and then locked, or you don't need to do this

Comment: The difference between `std::mutex` and `std::recursive_mutex` is precisely that `std::recursive_mutex`'s `lock()` method also contains some code to check to see if the current thread already owns the mutex, and if so it will increment an internal lock-count variable instead of putting the calling thread to sleep, thereby avoiding a deadlock in this scenario.  (The slight downside is that the additional logic takes a few additional CPU cycles to execute, compared to the plain `std::mutex` implementation)